# What is data striding?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, dma

In the DMA Controller description present in the datasheet of a Microchip microcontroller it states that the DMA has a "Programable independent data striding.." (see capture below)
[DMA characteristics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHccx.png)

What is data striding in this context?

I could only find this wikipedia article which is kind of related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_of_an_array

Thank you very much in advanced.

I was expecting to find an answer on the internet, including on stack overflow.

Comment: MCU manufacturers invent all manner of strange new terms all the time - don't assume that those terms are some sort of industry standard. You'll have to read the DMA part of the manual to tell what it does.

Comment: I think the wikipedia article explains it well.  The DMA can operate on every n-th element of an array.  This is useful if you want to operate on one column of a 2D array, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what it really was with an application note named "*AT17417: Usage of XDMAC on SAM S/SAM E/SAMV*". [Link here](https://device.report/m/32a46bc8e71da78cf74653953ec70e26f40bb9716fb06db5e8bb4f8309c19e51.pdf)

Memory data striding is defined as "*... a method of accessing memory in an interleaved (discontinuous) manner.*"

Here is an example from the application note, but there are tons of more detailed and complex examples:

[Simple Destination data striding with length 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSxJ7.png)